# How do I calculate threshold voltage from the graph?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, physics, graph

I have a table of values given to me which contains drain current Id (in μA) and gate voltage (in volts) calculated in the saturation region for a thin film transistor.

I need to find the threshold voltage by drawing a graph. I used Desmos to draw the graph based on the given values.

I know that threshold voltage is defined as the gate voltage at which a device starts to conduct, but I'm confused as to which gate voltage I should consider.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that X axis is in volts?

Comment: @JohnD Yes, it is in volts but maybe a printing mistake and actually it is in millivolts. But still, which point to consider?

Comment: "*I know that threshold voltage is defined as the gate voltage at which a device starts to conduct,*" If starting of conduction is where the \$I_d\$ first exceeds 0 \$\mu\$A then where is that on your graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to take square root of drain current and then plot it. Then extend the line to x-axis to get the intercept which is the threshold voltage.

Answer (score -1):

From [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_voltage):

> The threshold voltage, commonly abbreviated as Vth or VGS(th), of a
> field-effect transistor (FET) is the minimum gate-to-source voltage
> (VGS) that is needed to create a conducting path between the source
> and drain terminals.